How to concantenate a text box 'number' with the next number in MS Access
I have a large amount of data that is in the process of being put in a non-exsistant access database. There are numbers that are currently being used that are imparative to keep, problem is they are really a text string. Format: 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.1.3, 1.1.1.1.3.1 etc these strings are going up to nine numbers deep.
The end users are looking to be able to 'autofill' the next number in the string with a new record. I'm not even sure if this is a possiblity at this point. Any new record would be a child record from a pre-existing record with an established number, so I'd need the form to look at the main form number and then in the subform record add the next digit.
For example to keep things simple:
Main Form ID# is 1.1.1
Child Form ID# needs to be 1.1.1.1
Next record on child form would be 1.1.1.2
etc
I've got my child form related to my main form, and I've created a field for the concatenated data to go. I figure I have to set up the expression in the child form for this field, however I'm not sure how to go about creating an autonumber to go into the formula. I'm sure it's something simple but I'm not finding it.

Assigning custom unique identifier is a common topic and will require VBA. Whether or not it is "simple" depends on your level of expertise. Do research and when you have code with issue, post question.

Start with review of https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23329

Count the records of the subform to calculate the number.
Run code like this in the OnCurrent event of the subform:
Dim Records     As DAO.Recordset

Dim Count       As Integer
Dim NextNumber  as String

If IsNull(Me!Number.Value) Then
    ' Find the count of child records.
    Set Records = Me!RecordsetClone
    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Records.MoveLast    
    End If
    Count = Records.RecordCount
    Records.Close
    
    ' Concatenate the main form number, say 1.1.1, and the number of this record, say 2, to
    ' obtain 1.1.1.2 as the next number.
    NextNumber = Me.Parent!Number.Value & "." & CStr(Count)
    ' Assign this next number.
    Me!Number.Value = NextNumber
Else
    ' Number has been assigned previously.
End

